# Are Remote Events Receivers still an Up To Date approach to follow

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver

I want to run some logic after creating SharePoint online list items, the logic will be very complicated/lengthy  to write inside Power Automate. so is creating a remote event receiver a valid approach to follow? i do not want to use Power automate, as the flow will be very lengthy . so are Remote Event Receiver a way to go for? or it is considered obsolete in a way or another?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to use [SharePoint webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks) if possible, they are easier to consume since it's just an ordinary HTTP web API. Alternatively, you could use a Power Automate flow to trigger an Azure function.

Comment: ok i am reading about Azure Functions, but one concern i have is how i am going to secure the Azure functions calls? seems Azure functions can be called using Web ApI so does this mean that anyone who knows the end point url cancall the azure function ? i hope this is not the case thus.. thanks

Comment: There are many ways to secure the API endpoint, "Secure an HTTP endpoint in production" from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger Additionally, you can lock it down entirely and simply use an Azure storage queue or service bus queue trigger for your Azure function instead of a HTTP trigger

Comment: so if for the trigger options for the Azure Function, i select "Timer trigger" instead of "Http trigger" then the Azure function will not be callable using Http .. am i correct

Comment: I don't believe so, since it's not a HTTP trigger function anymore.

Comment: so i can secure the azure function from been called by anonymous users if i set the trigger action as "Timer trigger" instead of "Http trigger" .. at the end i want my azure function to run in the background each 15 minutes, i do not want it to be called by hhtp.. just to clarify i pass my question correctly.

Comment: It's not the only way to secure your function from anonymous users, regardless of what trigger you choose. This is off topic from the question and is more about function configuration rather than SharePoint, please check out the Microsoft documentation.